# Split up data in CSV file and writing to a file in slices using R

Tags: r, export-to-csv

I have a data in CSV file containing 956,678 rows. The following piece of code reads the file and splits the data in groups (each group having 65,000 rows and remainder rows go to last group) in R.

```
my_file <- read.csv("~myfile_path/file.csv")
grps <- (split(my_file, (seq(nrow(my_file))-1) %/% 65000))
for (i in grps)
{
write.csv(grps, paste("path/output_file", i, ".csv", sep=""))
}
```

Now, I would like to write these groups as CSV files to the disk. Can anyone suggest me how to do that?

**EDIT1:**

Based on the comments, I have modified the code and getting the following error:

> Error in data.frame(`0` = list(nih_addr_id = c(664L, 665L, 666L, 667L,  :
> arguments imply differing number of rows: 65000, 46677

Comment: `my_file` is already a data.frame.  You don't need the following statement.

Comment: `split(df, sample(1:round(nrow(df)/65000), 65000))` and then use a `for-loop` to `write.csv` each chunk in the list generated by the `split` operation.

Comment: @Abdou: Thanks for your feedback. Using split approach suggested by you. I got the following error: "Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'"

Comment: @Tensibai: I have edited the question what I have tried so far. I am getting the error.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: Thanks. Just edited the code based on your comment.

Comment: @JibranKhan sorry about that. Should have used `rep()` instead of `sample()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `write.csv` in the loop is trying to write the list as a .csv file, rather than the dataframe element of the list.

Try:

```
my_file <- read.csv("~myfile_path/file.csv")
grps <- (split(my_file, (seq(nrow(my_file))-1) %/% 65000))
for (i in seq_along(grps)) {
    write.csv(grps[[i]], paste0("path/output_file", i, ".csv"))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `lapply` and `data.table`, which is fast - even for large datasets. The file is chunked by splitting the vector `my_file_rows` in chunks of 65k by rownumbers as set by `chunk_size`. The remainder is automatically taken care of by using the `split` function. You can easily adjust the number of rows by adjusting the number in `chunk_size` to your preferences. This solution pastes the beginning rownumber of each chunk into the file name by pasting `x[1]`.

```
  my_file_rows <- seq(1, nrow(my_file))
  chunk_size <- 65e3

  lapply(split(my_file_rows, ceiling(my_file_rows/chunk_size)), function(x){

    fwrite(my_file[x,], paste0("path/output_file", x[1], ".csv"))

  })}
```